# Getting most recent time instead of max time

Tags: c

I need `maxhr` and `maxmin` to only record the highest time. Underneath my      `if((hr>maxhr)||((hr==maxhr)&&(min>maxmin)));` is where I am storing my int but it keeps returning the most recent time typed in. I understand the problem but don't know how to fix it.

Also, in that if statement, I am trying to say if the current hr is greater then my max OR if both my hours are equal but my current min is greater then my maxmin. Am I expressing this correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int hr;
    int min;
    int dives;
    int counter=0;
    int maxmin=0;
    int maxhr=0;
    int totmin=0;
    int tothr=0;
    printf("Please enter all dive times, one by one, with hours first and         minutes second, separated by a colon. Ex HH:MM\n");
    dives = scanf("%d:%d", &hr,&min);

    while(dives != EOF)
    {
        counter++;
        tothr = tothr+hr;
        totmin = totmin+min;
        if(totmin>59)
        {
            totmin = totmin-60;
            tothr = tothr+1;
        }
        if((hr>maxhr)||((hr==maxhr)&&(min>maxmin)));
        {
            maxhr = hr;
            maxmin = min;
        }
        dives = scanf("%d:%d", &hr,&min); 
    }
    printf("The longest dive is %d:%d\n",maxhr,maxmin);
    printf("The total dive time is %d:%d\n",tothr,totmin);
}
```

Comment: You really should not hide the `while` behind the `scanf`. You should check what `scanf` returns.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't simply convert hours and minutes into total minutes?

Comment: I am considering calculating total minutes but now my control d isn't ending the program like it used to. Also, is my maxhr = hr saving the value of hr to maxhr, or is it simply sharing the value of hr with maxhr. Because if it is simply sharing then doesn't maxhr change every time I put in any new value for hr?

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned statement, `if((hr>maxhr)||((hr==maxhr)&&(min>maxmin)))` has a semicolon at the end. Could that be your problem? The if statement looks like it's correct.

Comment: I removed the ";" but now my control d is no longer doing anything. Thoughts?

Comment: "Thoughts?" --- now debug it.